# Communication between different classes (Eclipse Forms communication between sections)

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

This problem can maybe be generalized as a class communication problem and maybe there is a solution/pattern that solves this specific one.

I am using eclipse forms in a RCP application, each form has many sections.

Most of the sections are dependent i.e. if the user modifies something in section A I want immediately some changes in section B. I do this using listeners and I have all the sections code in the same class but is there any way to communicate these changes without having the all the code together so I can write more clear code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Eclipse Databinding to implement dependencies between your Controls.

For example the following snippet binds the selection state of a checkbox to the enabled state of a textfield

```
ctx = new DataBindingContext();
ISWTObservableValue observe = WidgetProperties.selection().observe(myCheckBox);
ISWTObservableValue observe2 =  WidgetProperties.enabled().observe(myTextField);
ctx.bindValue(observe, observe2)
```

Comment: does this framework have also functionality for more complicated operations except selecting and enabling like setting table viewer data or text field text etc..?

Comment: What do you mean with "more complicated"? - There are a lot of Observables where you can track changes on controls or you can write your own Observables. In addition you can bind converters so that you can bind e.g. the value of a text-field to the expanded-state of a section, etc...